# Downgrade MariaDB databases

Tags: server, upgrade, mysql

I was running a MariaDB server with the version 10.1. I needed to update it, but I accidentally updated to 10.3 (Alpha) instead 10.2 (Stable), and my database was upgraded to v10.3 along with the server.

The problem is, the latest v10.3 MariaDB server does NOT run, it freezes when starting. I installed v10.2 again, but I got this error, meaning the database isn't compatible anymore:

```
/var/lib/mysql: found previous version 10.3
The file /var/lib/mysql/debian-10.3.flag indicates a
version that cannot automatically be upgraded. Therefore the
previous data directory will be renamed to /var/lib/mysql-10.3 and
a new data directory will be initialized at /var/lib/mysql.
Please manually export/import your data (e.g. with mysqldump) if needed.
```

Since the v10.3 doesn't start (it just freezes when starting), I cannot run mysqldump because the mysql server isn't running. Any thoughts on what I could do?

Comment: I got this error when switching from MySQL to MariaDB. The MySQL binary data files were not compatible with MariaDB so I switched back to MySQL because I did not have time to mess with mysqldump (first had to move MariaDB data away from /var/lib/mysql, then install MySQL, then copy my original data from /var/lib/mysql-5.7 to /var/lib/mysql).
Maybe you will have more answers by asking on MariaDB forums or mailing list.